# J meter open blank Screen

Tags: jmeter

[image]I have downloaded J meter on below spec machine , however when clicking on the apache.jar file it runs however it opens into a blank white screen attached Have tried the solution to add env variable J2D_D3D and setting to false...thank you in advance for your assistance

Device name DESKTOP-TFNU4Q1
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4800MQ CPU @ 2.70GHz   2.70 GHz
Installed RAM   16,0 GB
Device ID   21EA1CAF-A5F9-46D5-930B-73BFD811FC2A
Product ID  00331-60000-00000-AA668
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display

Edition Windows 10 Pro N
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎2021/‎02/‎05
OS build    19042.1288
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0

Comment: What do you see in the `JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter.log` file ? Also, what's the version of JDK used in your machine?

Answer (score 1):

Operating system per se should be the problem, I would rather [check your Java runtime version](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.html), most probably it's too new or too old or too specific

Also check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) for any suspicious entries, if it doesn't contain any useful information you can [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by changing this line:

```
<Root level="info">
```

to this one:

```
<Root level="debug">
```

in *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation). JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change.

Another thing to try is changing JMeter's ["look and feel"](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#laf_config) by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.laf=CrossPlatform
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when i open the ApacheJmeter.jar file, but when i open it from the bat file ( jmeter.bat ), it opens correctly.

The bat file is in the same folder where the jar file is. My Jmeter version is 5.4.1 and my java version is 17.0.1